# PHP Variables not passing to url correctly from API

Tags: php, api, url, url-shortener

I'm trying to use the Premium URL Shortener script from codecanyon, I have asked for support but they seem to be a little busy, so the response time is not to quick.

The issue I have is when the API sends the request to the url shortener script with the following shortened query for example purposes:

```
$short = "http://myurl/api?api=MYAPI&format=text&url=http://myfullwebsite.com/email/quote.php?fullname=$fullname&address=$address&emailaddress=$emailaddress";
```

Although the variables are being placed in the script correctly using echo function at the end of the script after the api request is sent shows they are correctly inserted like so:

```
http://myurl/api?api=MYAPI&format=text&url=http://myfullwebsite.com/email/quote.php?fullname=Dan Smith&address=12 Main Street, London&emailaddress=dan@smith.com
```

However if I click the shortened url provided to me from the script I only get the following url string appear in the browser:

```
http://myfullwebsite.com/email/quote.php?fullname=Dan
```

It seems as soon as there is a space or even if there is no second name such as Dan Smith and only Dan is the available name, it will not even apply the second ampersand or & sign.

I have tried to use `urlecode()` but still no joy and I've been pulling my hair out for the last 3 days!

As a novice beginner it has been somewhat difficult to try and achieve the end result and it seems unreachable so I would appreciate any kind help or advice if possible, Maybe I'm missing something so simple?

I've thought of having the url query build from an array of variables but as a novice I've tried one way and failed so not sure if I have done it wrong.

Here is my full api code where I have tried both with `SESSION` and `GET` but that is not the problem as the end result echos to the browser with the variables there.. it's only when you follow the shortened url link that you see they're missing.

```
    <?php
session_start();

$fullname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["fullname"]);
$address = htmlspecialchars($_GET["address"]);
$postcode = htmlspecialchars($_GET["postcode"]);
$emailaddress = htmlspecialchars($_GET["emailaddress"]);


$short = "http://myurl/api?api=MYAPI&format=text&url=http://ukhomesurveys.co.uk/email/quote.php?fullname=$fullname&address=$address&emailaddress=$emailaddress";


 echo $short;

// Using Plain Text Response
  $api_url = $short;
  $res= @file_get_contents($api_url);
  if($res){
    echo $res;
  }


?>
```

Hope I covered everything and hope I have not confused anyone. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried replacing the &s with &amp; in the url?

Comment: Hi Rob, Yes i have mate i tried that as the first option thinking it would be an easy fix but never was unfortunately :( it seems it just does not want to pickup the amp or & as soon as the url processes the first variable such as  fullname=Dan&emailaddress=Dan@smith.com.. Although  using echo proves the full string is being sent to the api the shortened url is not handling the process correctly i assume.

Answer (score 1):

I think the good choice here is to encode your query with base64 and then pass it to the shortener. In your http://myfullwebsite.com/email/quote.php you just decode the query and use it. The standart PHP functions are base64_encode and base64_decode.

Comment: can you provide an example as to what you mean interms of the base64 encode?

Comment: I mean you take the entire query string(param=val&param=val...) and encode it, then use quote.php?encoded=base64_encoded_string and then decode it in your quote.php

Comment: Wont that only work correctly using post method though?  As what is happening is when the user or me for example while in testing mode goes the the shortened url  instead of having all the variables and values follow the url so i would follow this for example:  http://to.com/TeSt   and it should instantly redirect me to:  http://mywebsite.com/quote.php?fullname=Value-Set&emailaddress=Value-Set&address=Value-Set  but instead its only giving you http://mywebsite.com/quote.php?fullname=(first Part of the value if it has spaces)  so fullname=Dan   and the rest would not be shown.

Comment: It will work with GET too. Because you just pass the string value. And base64 string does not contain spaces, so the URL shoud be correctly shortened.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to encode URI using [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.rawurlencode.php)?

```
$url = rawurlencode('http://myfullwebsite.com/email/quote.php?fullname=Dan Smith&address=12 Main Street, London&emailaddress=dan@smith.com');
```

Comment: Unixarmy, to be honest i cant remember if i did or not but i sure will try it now.  would you recommend running it as:  $url = rawurlencode('http://myfullwebsite.com/email/quote.php?fullname=$fullname&address=$address&emailaddress=$emailaddress'); or would you use:  
$url = rawurlencode('http://myfullwebsite.com/email/quote.php?fullname='.$fullname.'&address='.$address.'&emailaddress='.$emailaddress'); notice the single ' quotes and .$fullname.

Comment: If you're using single quoted strings, it should looks like [this.](http://pastebin.com/AckYvh45)

Comment: Unfortunately its not worked, using the rawurlencode stopped the shortener even providing a url so i switched the rawurlencode to just encode the variables as still no joy :(